# Convert htaccess file to nginx try_file for subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, nginx-config

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

How to convert apache .htaccess file to nginx try_file?

I have static html files in the following folder structure and accessing them with pretty URL style without .html extensions it was working with apache but when I try to convert nginx config it was throwing 404 for subfolders. I used https://winginx.com/en/htaccess site for conversion.

```
# nginx configuration

location / {
  rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html break;
}
```

```
+ root-folder  
  + index.html  - url - www.hello.com
  + abc.html  - url - www.hello.com/abc
  + .........   
  + xyz.html  - url - www.hello.com/xyz  
  + category-folder   
     + category1.html  - url - www.hello.com/category-folder/category1
     + category2.html  - url - www.hello.com/category-folder/category2
     + category3.html  - url - www.hello.com/category-folder/category3
  + page-folder 
     + page1.html - url - www.hello.com/page-folder/page1
     + page2.html - url - www.hello.com/page-folder/page2
     + page3.html - url - www.hello.com/page-folder/page3
```

Any help will be really apricated.

Comment: Try: `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `try_files` is a good directive for front-controller patterns of dynamic frameworks powered by PHP or other languages, where you have a single bootstrap file, e.g. `/index.php`, which "serves" the SEO friendly URLs:

```
/foo/ -> /index.php
/bar/ -> /index.php
/lorem/ipsum -> /index.php
```

If your files are static and you know the file structure in advance, `try_files` brings nothing other than the performance penalty of `stat` (file existence check) system calls.

E.g. applying `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;` from a comment by Richard, would mean that for URI `/category-folder/category1`, NGINX first checks that actual file `/category-folder/category1` exists first, then checks if `/category-folder/category1.html` exists, and in case it doesn't, check if `/category-folder/category1/` directory exists.

It makes much sense to stick to `rewrite` and converting configuration, in this case, is pretty straightforward. It will result in 1:1 match on how it worked in Apache.

Using my "fairly sophisticated" [Apache to NGINX config converter](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx), which does detect when you need to use `try_files` and when not,  you will get the desired rewrite (place this directly in `server` context, not in `location`):

```
rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.html last;
```

To check this rewrite you can use [this test](https://regex101.com/r/zsaQuk/1).

As you see, the only trick there is that URIs in NGINX rewrites (and URIs specified in NGINX in general) have to start with slash, whereas in Apache they are omitted.